# Approximately how long will it take to document all existing species?

Tags: species

I did some research and found that there is a new estimate of 8.7 million species, plus or minus 1.3 million and that about 1.2 million have been discovered already. About how long will it take to discover the remaining species?

I just did a bit more research and found that about 18,000 species are discovered each year. If this rate continues, then the remaining 7.5 million species would be discovered in about 416.667 years. If we subtract the 1.3 million to get 6.2 million and divide that by 18K, then we get 344.444 years. If we add 1.3 million to get 8.8 million and divide by 18K, then we get 488.889 years. So by my calculation, it would be anywhere from 344 years to 489 years (rounded). Is this about right? Or are there other factors that could come into play?

Comment: Whoever downvoted, would you mind explaining why?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but it's usually useful to include in the main post links to where you found those statistics.

Comment: I voted to close this question because many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

Comment: I voted to close your question because I think that it is not a question about biology in the terms of SE Biology as laid out in the [tour]. You may wish to review the three types of question listed there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For one thing, the species concept is already a little fuzzy when it comes to macroeukaryotes, but it gets especially fuzzy when you get into single-celled organisms (which I'm guessing these estimates ignore). So, estimating the number of species will depend on who you are looking at and where you are looking. Secondly, the number of species in an ecosystem (or in this case on a planet) is not fixed. Evolution is a dynamic process which is always occurring. Populations divide and re-converge, and new species emerge, old species go extinct. The circle of life and all that.

But more importantly, extrapolating the rate of new discoveries out at a constant rate basically assumes that all species have an equal probability of being discovered at all times. Which we know isn't the case. Even if all of the species on earth were equally abundant and equally distributed, this discovery rate would not remain constant.

Imagine a giant lotto ball machine with a seemingly infinite number of balls in it, each with a random number on it. Your job is to sample this machine and document each *unique* lotto ball number. Say you're sampling one ball per minute. At first, almost every new lotto ball you pick is unique. You're discovering around 60 unique numbers every hour. But after a while, you start to see some numbers repeated, and after an extended amount of time you notice that more than half the balls you sample are already accounted for. You're now discovering less than 30 new balls per hour. The more you sample and record, the lower your rate of new discoveries becomes. Eventually, you are lucky if you can find a unique discovery in any given day of sampling. But you still have no idea whether you have sampled and documented *ALL* of the unique numbers in the machine.

If you plot the cumulative number of unique numbers you see vs the sampling depth, you get something like a species accumulation curve or a [collector's curve](https://terrestrialecosystems.com/species-accumulation-curves/). These generally form an asymptotic shape, like this [example](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/An-example-of-a-collectors-curve-Cumulative-sample-size-represents-the-number-of_fig2_242278779) below. You can use some statistics based on the general shape of these curves to estimate the total number of unique species in a system. It requires making some assumptions about your sampling methods and also about the distribution of your different species, but, in any sufficiently complex community, you end up with this sort of diminishing return rate after extensive sampling.

[image: Example of collector's curve].

Obviously, researchers are not necessarily sampling new species at random, nor are they sampling at a fixed rate. Technology is a big factor, and research funding in general will affect the rate at which new species can be discovered. But you also have to keep in mind that undiscovered species are not distributed evenly withing or between different ecosystems, and they do not have equal probability of discovery at all times. To return to our bingo ball metaphor, every different ecosystem is like a different bingo machine. In some of them, species might occur in roughly equal ratios, but in others they might have dramatically skewed ratios. Some might outnumber others by a ratio of a million to one or more. And as we add more and more to the cumulative list, those remaining undiscovered are likely to be the more rare and hard to find species.

Given all of the potential factors that might go into determining the rate of new species discovery, it would be difficult if not impossible to estimate when our efforts would reach complete saturation, but it will almost certainly slow down as greater and greater numbers of species are discovered.